# Set value from database based on row we choose by button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to make a form for my office, where users can fill the form
without manually typing.
Just search from the popup browser, and find their data and automatically set in fields.

This is form display, 
when we click the blue file icon to open new popup window
[image: we click blue file icon to open new popup window]

And this is new popup window, search display.
When we click button 'pilih' i want ('nik, nama_karyawan, departemen, jabatan')
to automatically set in form display.

[image: and when we click button 'pilih']

Comment: You can easily do this with jquery just show html of your pop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to send parameters to opener window. You can do it easily by using **[window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp)** Below is the sample code that works fine for me:

In parent window:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btnOpenPopup').click(function(){
             window.open("popup.html", "userList", "width=200, height=100");
        });     
    });
</script>

<form name="test">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnOpenPopup">Open</a>

    <br /><br />
    <label>Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
</form>
```

In popup window:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('table tr').click(function(){
            firstName = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
            lastName = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();

            window.opener.$('input[name="firstname"]').val(firstName);
            window.opener.$('input[name="lastname"]').val(lastName);

            window.close();
        });
    });
</script>
<table width="80%">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Last name</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>Albert</td>
            <td>Potter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Melis</td>
            <td>Some Last Name</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to set the table data from database. If you retrieve your data from database in your data table (in popup), and loop through the results in table row you're done.

Comment: wah, that's great! nice suggest for looping throigh the results in table row :). thank you sir.